# Is a strictly convex function "Lipschitz from below"

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. It is known that if $f$ is convex then $f$ is locally Lipschitz, i.e. for every $\epsilon>0$ and $x^* \in \mathbb{R}^n$, there exists $M>0$ such that:

$\Vert f(x)-f(x^*) \Vert \leq M\Vert x-x^*\Vert \qquad \forall x \in N_{\epsilon}(x^*)$

However, if $f$ is *strictly* convex, is it also the case that for every $\epsilon>0$ and $x^* \in \mathbb{R}^n$, there exists $M>0$ such that:

$M\Vert x-x^*\Vert \leq \Vert f(x)-f(x^*) \Vert  \qquad \forall x \in N_{\epsilon}(x^*)$

Or sort of "Lipschitz from below" (I don't know if there's terminology for this concept).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you allow $M=0$, then trivially yes.

If you require $M>0$, then no. For example take $n=1$, $f(x)=x^2$, and then $\epsilon=3$, $x^*=-1$, $x=1$.

Comment: Thanks! Would it be true if I enforced that the neighborhood does not contain a global minimum?

Comment: @ghiufhe: Only for $n=1$. In higher dimensions _every_ neighborhood of anywhere will contain points with the same values of $f$.